# PaperTrail has_many associations not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I am attempting to set up paper_trail to restore has_many associations. For my toy example, I have two classes:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_paper_trail
end
```

and

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  has_paper_trail
end
```

My code to test this is:

```
a = Article.new
Article.transaction do
  a.comments << Comment.new
  a.comments << Comment.new
  a.save
  a.touch_with_version
end
Article.transaction do
  c = Comment.new
  c.save
  ids = a.comment_ids
  ids.pop
  ids.push c.id
  a.comment_ids = ids
  a.touch_with_version
end
previous_a = a.versions.first.next.reify(has_many: true)
pp previous_a.comments
```

Where I would expect the output to be the comments with IDs 1 and 2 (i.e. the first two comments I created). However, the actual output I get is:

```
╰─ ~ rails r lib/one_time/paper_trail.rb
[#<Comment:0x0055a54ae3b148
  id: 3,
  text: nil,
  article_id: nil,
  created_at: Tue, 17 May 2016 04:28:24 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 17 May 2016 04:28:24 UTC +00:00>]
```

Is this something that I am doing incorrectly, or is this a glitch in the PaperTrail gem? It seems like I have everything set up correctly, and that my final line should be restoring the article to its original state with the first two comments saved to it.

Comment: I have the repository I'm using pushed up [here](https://github.com/elju/paper_trail_testing). You can run the command above to reproduce my result

Comment: Thanks for testing this experimental feature! Can you try removing the first transaction? I bet you'll get the results you expect. You may be experiencing a known issue with transactions: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/542